# How get ASP.NET Core Identity Forgot Password Page for Blazor working

Tags: blazor, asp.net-core-identity, blazor-webassembly

I have created a Blazor Application. For Login I use the standard ASP.NET Core Identity. This is working. But when I use the ForgotPassword-Page, enter the mailadress, I will not receive any mail. I think I have to configure the Mailservice somewhere but I don't find how I have to do this. Can someone help me, how I can get the forgot password feature working?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you have to implement an email service and register it on startup.cs
There are a lot of tutorials about this just google it